# What's the limit of $\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}\left ( 1+\frac{i}{n^2} \right)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

What is the limit of $a_{n}$ when n approaches infinity?

pls give me insight about how to approach the problem.

$a_{n} =\prod_{i=1}^{i=n}\left ( 1+\frac{i}{n^2} \right)$

I encountered this problem reading a book about undergraduate algebra(the book language is not in English, I couldn't find a good reference.). Although the problem was answered in the book using Stirling's approximation, the answer was kind of ungly.

Comment: Taking the logarithm and using the Taylor approximation $\log(1+x)=x+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$, we find $$
\log a_n  = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\log \left( {1 + \frac{i}{{n^2 }}} \right)}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{i}{n}}  + \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right)\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\left( {\frac{i}{n}} \right)^2 } .
$$ Can you finish from here?

Comment: Is the answer 1?

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta No it is not.

Comment: If you don't have any clue, you could try some arithmetic, simplification, or see some initial terms of the product notation. What have you tried?

Comment: @Gary a pretty hint :)

Comment: I know Taylor approximation of log(1+x) but I haven't seen this O notation in math.

Comment: @gigili $\mathcal{O}(x^2)$ denotes a function which can be bounded in absolute value by a fixed constant multiple of $x^2$ in a neighbourhood of $x=0$. In fact, $$
\left| {\log (1 + x) - x} \right| \le \frac{1}{2}x^2 
$$ for $x \geq 0$.

Comment: let me think for 5 minute.

Comment: @Gary this is what I have come up with.
$a_n = \sum ln(1+\frac{i}{n^2}) = \sum (\frac{i}{n^2}) + O(n^2) \sim \sum (\frac{i}{n^2}) =\frac{1}{2} \rightarrow a_n = e^\frac{1}{2}$
is it correct?

Comment: @gigili Almost. The error term is $$
\mathcal{O}\!\left( {\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {\frac{{i^2 }}{{n^4 }}} } \right) = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{{n^4 }}\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n {i^2 } } \right) = \mathcal{O}\!\left( {\frac{1}{n}} \right).
$$ This of course does not change the final answer.

Comment: @Gary thank you. God bless you.

Comment: @gigili [it is important to show](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards) what have you tried!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the fact that $ \left(\forall x\in\left[0,1\right]\right),\ \mathrm{e}^{x-x^{2}}\leq 1+x\leq\mathrm{e}^{x}$, we have :

\begin{aligned}\exp{\left(\frac{i}{n^{2}}-\frac{i^{2}}{n^{4}}\right)}\leq 1+\frac{i}{n^{2}}\leq\exp{\left(\frac{i}{n^{2}}\right)}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \\ \Longrightarrow\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \prod_{i=1}^{n}{\exp{\left(\frac{i}{n^{2}}-\frac{i^{2}}{n^{4}}\right)}}\leq\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\left(1+\frac{i}{n^{2}}\right)}\leq\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\exp{\left(\frac{i}{n^{2}}\right)}}\ \ \ \\ \iff\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \exp{\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i}-\frac{1}{n^{4}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i^{2}}\right)}\leq\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\left(1+\frac{i}{n^{2}}\right)}\leq\exp{\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{i=1}^{n}{i}\right)}\\ \iff \exp{\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}-\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{n^{3}}\right)}\leq\prod_{i=1}^{n}{\left(1+\frac{i}{n^{2}}\right)}\leq\exp{\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right)}\ \ \ \ \end{aligned}

Since $ \exp{\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}-\frac{\left(n+1\right)\left(2n+1\right)}{n^{3}}\right)} $ and $ \exp{\left(\frac{n+1}{2n}\right)} $ both approach $ \exp{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)} $ as $ n\to +\infty $, using squeezing theorem, we have : $$ \prod_{i=1}^{n}{\left(1+\frac{i}{n^{2}}\right)}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}\sqrt{\mathrm{e}} $$

Comment: [fyi](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards)